# AngularJS app in GAE gets CORS error

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, cors

I have a number of apps on GAE for Python and one based on AngularJS. The others are working fine, and the AngularJS one used to work OK. Now I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxxxxxxxx/rest/loadlocale?locale=en.
>   Redirect from 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx/rest/loadlocale?locale=en' to
>   'https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&......
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xxxxxxxx' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

If I go to ServiceLogin explicitly from Chrome, the the app will work OK for a while. After a while (I assume when the login expires) the error crops up again.

app.yaml has the following section:

```
- url: /rest/.*
  script: main.APP
  login: required
  secure: always
```

but removing "`secure: always`" makes no difference.

The error occurs at the first client http request, but the Python server code for the request handler shows no sign of ever being 
accessed.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs due the fact you have `login: required` in your `app.yaml` meaning that all XMLHttpRequest request will require a valid session.

GAE's `login` is handled by Google Accounts. So you can't change your settings.

Try removing `login` from `app.yaml`. If you only want certain request to be allowed without a valid Google session you need to specify what are allow and not. For instance:

```
- url: /rest/loadlocale
  script: main.APP
  login: optional # this is the default value and can be removed.
  secure: always

- url: /rest/.*
  script: main.APP
  login: required
  secure: always
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't do it. Same error. I noticed that other apps that work fine also sometimes have a 302 (redirect) response code. So something else is going on. Could it be that since it originates from XXXX.appspot.com/rest rather than XXXX.appspot.com it triggers a CORS error?